# Bootstrap and Struts2 form with validation

Tags: forms, validation, struts2

I'm using struts2 in my project and I'm trying to add bootstrap responsive features.

I have a form with validation (via xml and class validation())

Now the form look like this:

```
<s:form action="Welcome" method="post" validate="true">
       <div class="form-group row">
           <div >
              <small id="passwordHelp" class="text-danger">Must be 8-20 characters long.</small>      
            </div>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-danger">Password</label>
            <div >
                <input type="password" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </s:form>
```

the problem is that the error message is shown in any case (even at the first call of the jsp with the form (befor the submit itself)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by error message? You've set error classes to it. Why it shouldn't show it?

Comment: @AleksandrM I mean validation error. so when you see a form for the first time you don't have too see any validation error. You have to see them only after a subit with error in some fields. This is my problem. the errors for the fields are always shown

Comment: I guess you should use `is-invalid` class for that tag when `<s:if test=hasActionError`.